# PDO error when Fetching results

Tags: php, pdo, row, fetch, fetchall

I am trying to show results from a simple select statement using PDO

```
<?php  
    // Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
     include('config.inc');
     $user = $_POST['user']; 
     $password = $_POST['password'];


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where user = '$user' AND password ='$password'";
      $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
      $stm->execute();
      // here you go:
      $users = $stm->fetchAll();

      foreach ($users as $row) {
           print $row["user"] . "-" . $row["password"] ."<br/>";
      }

    ?>
```

And the only thing I get is errors like this one:

Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\proyect\select.php on line 16

Perhaps is something really simple I might be overlooking in this test, I am working with php 5.3.5.

This is the included file:

```
  <?php
          $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=carrito';
          $username = 'root';
          $password = 'root';

          try {
               $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
               $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          }catch (PDOException $e){
               $error_message = $e->getMessage();
               //include('db_error.php');
               echo $error_mesage;
               file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
               exit();
          }
?>
```

Comment: why are you inserting your variables directly, when you are using `prepare()`?? You should be utilizing placeholders, and putting `$user` and `$password` in your `execute()`

Comment: If you have `Undefined index: user` you not posting a field with name `user`. Are you sure that is your field name? Could it be `username`? To find error is PDO take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/689579

Comment: Didnt I just said it was a test? Its not like im using it in the real world... I just want it to show some results. Of course I know about the parameter binding.

Comment: I am sure...  I just checked. Also query errors do pop up. And in this case there is no query error. Just the PDO errors.

Comment: So what PDO errors are appearing?

Comment: Change `print $row["user"] . "-" . $row["password"] ."<br/>";` to `print_r($row)."<br/>";` to see what column names/values are in your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may guess:

you have `PDO::CASE_UPPER` set.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php
or your column name is just simply upper cased naturally.

But...stop wondering and start investigating. Simply do

```
var_dump($users);
```

to see what you have.

Comment: *self-facepalm* Thats the only bloody thing I didnt move in the problem that matters. I was trying... to make it simple so someone... made a constructive comment. Thanks a bunch, you are that person.

Answer (score -1):

Remove:

```
$users = $stm->fetchAll();

      foreach ($users as $row) {
           print $row["user"] . "-" . $row["password"] ."<br/>";
      }
```

And try this:

```
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   print $row["user"] . "-" . $row["password"] ."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: No dice... It is annoying because I just did it without PDO and it worked... as soon as I started with PDO this happened.